# Number of concurrent search requests on ElasticSearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, indexing, lucene, threadpool, amazon-opensearch

My objective is to calculate 2 things
Q1: how many search requests can a elasticsearch cluster can work on at once
Q2: how many search requests can a elasticsearch cluster hold in it's queue before starting rejecting it (producting 429 - Too many requests)

Say elasticsearch cluster(v6.8) has

- 8 data nodes of r5.xlarge instance i.e. 4 vCPU's.
- 3 master nodes of m5.xlarge.search i.e. 4 vCPU's
- 12 indices
- each index has 16 primary and 16 replica shards

**Please help with the approach on how one can go about answering the above questions given this cluster configuration?** (Assume 1 search request hits all indices and shards)

---

My attempt at calculating it:

In the Elasticsearch documentation it is mentioned:

> For count/search/suggest operations. Thread pool type is `fixed` with a size of `int((` [`# of allocated processors`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-threadpool.html#node.processors) `* 3) / 2) + 1`, and queue_size of `1000`.

So, according to me **each node** has a

- thread pool of 7 as number of processors is ((4*3)/2) + 1.
- The queue size for the same is 1000.
- This means number of threads available in the entire cluster = 8 (# data nodes) * 7 (# thread pool each node)= 56

Assuming 1 search request hits all indices in worst case

- Each request will produce number of indices * number of shards number of requests in the search queue = 12 * 16 = 192

1. So number of requests that can be worked upon at once = 56/192 ? (which looks wrong)
2. Number of searches it can hold in queue before rejecting them =
   (num nodes * queue size per node)/(num of sub requests each request produces) = (8 * 1000)/192 ~ 41 requests (which seems quite less).